# Is home property in MaterialApp necessary to run Application?

Tags: flutter

At compile time it show no problem but after running a program, it shows following error in console.

```
For the "/" route, the "home" property, if non-null, is used
```

Here is my code:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello world',
    
    );
  }
}
```

I am new in flutter and i want to know reasons why flutter give this error?
[image: Error showing in Emulator]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This error occurs because you don't have either `routes` or `home` properties in the `MaterialApp` class, so you can add either home property with the class that has build method that container `Scaffold` class.
so the easiest way, (if you don't have routes for multiple screens) is to add a `home` property like this:

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Hello world',
      home: YourClassName(),
    );
  }
}
```

After that, you can create `YourClassName` and it could be a stateless or stateful widget like this example:

```
class YourClassName extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(child: Text("some text")),
    );
  }
}
```

I wish that helps you

---